# authenticate in mvc and redirect to silverlight, how to access authenticated user?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, silverlight, forms-authentication

I am new to silverlight and working on a silverlight application hosted in mvc. User will login in aspx page **/LogOn** and will be redirected to either silverlight application or another view. To access logged user in silverlight Authentication service is added in mvc.

app.xaml.cs modified based on [Enable authentication in RIA services](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee707353%28v=vs.91%29.aspx)

```
    public App()
    {
        this.Startup += this.Application_Startup;
        this.Exit += this.Application_Exit;
        this.UnhandledException += this.Application_UnhandledException;

        InitializeComponent();

        WebContext webcontext = new WebContext
                                    {
                                        Authentication = new FormsAuthentication()
                                    };
        this.ApplicationLifetimeObjects.Add(webcontext);
        WebContext.Current.Authentication.LoadUser().Completed += 
            (s, e) => MessageBox.Show(WebContext.Current.User.Name);
    }
```

This is approach is not working as Message box is shown as empty

Answer (score 1):

You can create a WCF service with that attribute:

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

This will enable access to currently loged in User Identity.

```
    if(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
    {
        return HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
    }

    else
    {
        return null;
    }
```